# Tkinter Object has no attribute 'bind'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I'm trying to learn about python GUI's but I can't figure out how to bind stuff.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def leftClick(event):
    print("Left click")

frame = Frame(root,width=300,height=250).pack()
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)

root.mainloop()
```

but...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui2.py", line 8, in <module>
    frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Comment: change `frame = Frame(root,width=300,height=250).pack()` to `frame = Frame(root,width=300,height=250)` and add `frame.pack()`

Comment: @eyllanesc is correct, the `pack()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on eyllanesc's answer, the code should be

```py
frame = Frame(root,width=300,height=250)
frame.pack()
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)
```

In general, methods (like `pack`) that modify the original object don't return anything. Your code created a `Frame` object, then called `pack` and stored the output in `frame`. This is equivalent to writing `frame = None`. You need to first store the object as `frame` and then modify it.

Also, a good package to start with for GUIs in Python is [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/tutorial/), if you're interested.